# Искусственный интелект

Tags: нейронные-сети

Подскажите, что почитать, чтобы написать нейронную сеть для распознавания образов. (Желательно материал, который вам помог, а не первые ссылки из гугла. Можно и английском.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://www.machinelearning.ru, http://www.aiportal.ru/